# Exception in sumTypeTopicCounts

Tags: mallet

Hi I am trying to use MALLET to obtain 500 topics but I hit the below exception in MALLET.  Is this a known issue and are there any workarounds?

```
   overflow in merging on type 4975
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
            at cc.mallet.topics.ParallelTopicModel.sumTypeTopicCounts(ParallelTopicModel.java:453)
            at cc.mallet.topics.ParallelTopicModel.estimate(ParallelTopicModel.java:825)
            at cc.mallet.topics.tui.TopicTrainer.main(TopicTrainer.java:245)
```

I am using mallet-2.0.8RC2.

Comment: The same error occured to me. Let me add my observations.
It doesn't seem to be related to the number of topics -- I successfully mined huge models with 5000 topics but for instance failed mining 25 topics on a small dataset. The error is hard to reproduce and seems non deterministic -- I started the 25-topics-process again and the model was estimated successfully.
Edit: I am using mallet 2.0.8

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I ran **Mallet** with two different datasets (one with 100M and the other one around 1G). Usually this kind of exception happened with the larger dataset and when I wanted to run in in parallel for larger iteration number like 100 for the larger dataset. It threw **Exception: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** in two different files:  **WorkerRunnable** and **ParallelTopicModel** in different spots. So the thing is when the array reaches the end of the array, it prints “**overflow in merging on type**” to the logger and after that point, the program doesn’t do anything to get out of the situation. I was able to patch these edge cases with index checking before accessing the array. It helps me run it without breaking it but I am not sure how it might change the output anyways and it also keeps printing the same message “**overflow in merging on type** ” as usual but it goes on and doesn’t throw an exception.

I have uploaded the patches on [my Github](https://github.com/hkarbasi/Mallet) and follow the instructions. It has been able to resolve the issues for me as I haven’t seen this break again under different circumstances. If it doesn’t resolve your issues, you should probably download the latest version from [their Github](https://github.com/mimno/Mallet) and debug and build it yourself.

I have also uploaded both datasets; both are four years of data; (1 Jan 2015- 1 Jan 2019), smaller one is StackExchange (DataScience) and the larger one is Reddit (9 DataScience Subreddits) ([datasets](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q8Dvm-54CgLj-bmVxD6i1hvRT_WhYhpV)) and you would like to play with it.

Good luck.